# Xcode Instruments error: "Allocations tracking library was not loaded in time"

Tags: ios, profiling, ios-simulator, instruments

Problem started when installed Xcode5 bundle. I'm using Mavericks - not sure if that is relevant.

Cannot profile allocations in simulator.
Instruments would load and start app in the simulators but instead of allocations log I see this:
[image: screenshot]

Did anyone face this problem?

Comment: Same issue here. Persists after restart, clean build folder, remove derived data...

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856494/allocations-tracking-library-was-not-loaded-in-time-and-unable-to-see-stack-trac

Answer (score 4):

Also got this error:
If the simulator was set to "iPhone" (iOS6), and active scheme was iOS7, then I got this error as well.

Solution:
So either set your active scheme to an iOS6 device, or change hardware in the simulator to an iOS7 device.

Comment: So it's 2015 and this is still relevant. Could you please explain what you mean by "set your active scheme to an iOS6 device"?  (obviously not iOS6 these days)

Comment: For me the problem was the same but updated. Basically instruments aren't working when set to iOS7 SIM but worked fine using iPhone 6 (iOS 8). I'm guessing instruments only work on latest OS?