# Allocations tracking library was not loaded in time and unable to see stack trace

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, instruments

[image]For opening Instruments we must profile first then select which template we have to profile memory leaks,allocations,zombies. But still I get the error allocations library was not loaded, and could not see the stack trace also. And could not find the reason of leak in the application

As mentioned solution in other links, I am using both simulator (iOS7), and active scheme (iOS7)

Xcode Version:Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)
Simulator: iOS 7.0.3 (111B508)
Mac: OS X Version 10.8.5

Please excuse if any information above is incorrect. Please give answers..Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode Instruments error: "Allocations tracking library was not loaded in time"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625082/xcode-instruments-error-allocations-tracking-library-was-not-loaded-in-time)

Answer (score 3):

I'm running into the issue on iOS 7 simulator.   I still don’t know how to fix this, but I may have found a workaround.

1. Tap on “Record button” to stop the instrument if it’s running.
2. Select Instrument -> Delete ‘Allocations’ Instrument…  menu. You can see only ‘Leaks’ in the Instruments
3. Tap on “Record button” to star the instrument. Start your application on the simulator.
4. Tap on Library button and drag “Allocations” onto Instruments. You can see 'Leaks' and "Allocations" in the Instruments

I can see the stack trace after Step 4.

Comment: This workaround works only for a few seconds and then crashes for me. Also noticed that the first time it is done Instruments asks for administrator password to enable analyzing processes, which makes me think this happens between Xcode/Instruments updates.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this in Xcode 8.3 and it was caused by Build Configuration mismatch for Run and Profile. 
[image]
Profiler tried to run Release type of application which was not even built.
[image]
So it caused the error.
[image]
After changing Profile Build Configuration to product type that was already built, in my case Debug, it resolved the issue and Instruments worked again.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case it only works using the iOS simulator version 8.1 +.

Also, don't forget to change to 8.1 in the project *Build Settings* under *iOS Deployment Target*