# Allocations tracking library was not loaded in time - doesn't work on ios 7

Tags: ios, xcode, nszombies, xcode6.3.1

I'm  trying to run zombies instrument with an ios 7.1 simulator but I receive the error "Allocation tracking library was not loaded in time".
When I try to run zombie with an ios 8.3 simulator it works.
I'm working with xcode 6.3.1, and zombie is enabled in Scheme. 
Doe's anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625082/xcode-instruments-error-allocations-tracking-library-was-not-loaded-in-time